# Multiple text color in one spark:TextInput

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, colors, textinput, flex-spark

How can I color words in **spark:TextInput** with *two or more colors*?

I did it with **mx:TextInput** with **htmlText** property but i can not find it in **spark** component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:TextArea id="txt_ar"  textAlign="justify"
borderAlpha="0" editable="false">
```

then  write ur html string

```
textrichtml:String = "your html string"
```

then use following code.

```
txt_ar.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(textrichtml,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```